# Panel to the right disappeared (properties? Not the one you toggle with N)

Tags: interface

I'm new to the software, using blender 2.78 on an iMac with OS X 10.6.8.
I've been working on a file for a few days now, when a important panel to the right suddenly disappeared.

This is how it looks right now:

[image: this is how it looks right now]

The panel marked in red in this picture is the one i need:

[image: how it should look]

Notice how the three lines in the corners that you can grab to change the size of view windows/panels also is gone in the file I'm working on. Marked with green circle in top right corner.

Edit: Solved the problem by opening the file with "load UI" unchecked. Still wonder why the three lines in the corners of the panels disappeared though.

Comment: You probably hit `Shit + Space` and made the 3D view fullscreen

Comment: Probably you have hit Ctrl+"Arrow up or down" or Command+"Arrow up or down" which allows to focus on the view your mouse cursor is on

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos... it seems, both are working!! But I did not know yours...

Comment: This is why I love BSE, after so many years of using a software we can still find hidden features :)